# How to get the value of the Rangepicker which having the time with Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetimepicker, antd, daterangepicker

I have a table of Rangepicker of the date and  the time, this table is dynamically which I can add and remove these range picker as you look at the picture below : 
[image]

I want to store these values on another table to send it to the backend and when I have value on the Rangepicker, I get an error.

My code is :

```
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import fr_FR from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/fr_FR';
import "moment/locale/fr";
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        tranches :[{date:null}]
    }
  onChange(value, dateString) {
    console.log('Selected Time: ', value);
    console.log('Formatted Selected Time: ', dateString)
  }
  onOk(value) {
    console.log('onOk: ', value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         { 
                      this.state.tranches.map((el, i) => 
                        <Row key={i}>
                          <Col span={12}>
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <label className="pt-label .modifier"><strong>Période</strong></label>
                            <LocaleProvider locale={fr_FR}>
                              <RangePicker 
                                allowClear={false}
                                id="date" name= "date"
                                style={{ width: '547px', marginLeft:'20px'}} 
                                locale="fr" 
                                //placeholder={["Date de début","Date de fin"]} 
                                separator="-" 
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                showTime={{ format: 'HH:mm' }}
                                format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
                                placeholder={['Date et heure de début', 'Date et heure de fin']}
                                onOk={this.onOk}
                              />
                            </LocaleProvider>
                          </Col>
                          <Col span={12}>
                            {i === 0 ? 
                                        <>                      
                                      <Icon type="plus-circle" theme="twoTone" twoToneColor="#52c41a"  onClick={this.ajouterTranche}/> 
                                          <br/> 
                                        </>
                                      :
                                        <>
                                       <Icon type="close-circle" theme="twoTone" twoToneColor="red"  onClick={this.supprimerTranche(i)}/>

                                          <Icon type="plus-circle" theme="twoTone" twoToneColor="#52c41a"  onClick={this.ajouterTranche}/>  
                                          <br/>
                                        </> 
                                      }
                          </Col>
</Row>
                    )}
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox? Looks okay to me. You need to store it to your state in the onOk() and be sure to remove it if the x icon is pressed.

Comment: @ShivamGupta this is my codeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/53nr9w4l9n

Comment: Okay, so the state declaration causes it to always remain today's date and a month from today.

Comment: @ShivamGupta the decalaration is the tranches of the state

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/719qvv8v11?fontsize=14

Comment: Here you go, you had to pass the context with the onChange() so that you can add the required date. 
FYI, be sure to check the remove functionality, it doesn't work as expected in above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
onChange(value, dateString) {
 console.log('Selected Time: ', value);
 console.log('Formatted Selected Time: ', dateString)
}
```

to

```
onChange = (value, dateString) => {
 let date = this.state.date
 date.push(value)
 this.setState({date: date})
}
```

Link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/719qvv8v11?fontsize=14)
The x icon is not functional in the above link

Comment: Thank you @Shivam, but, when I remove it on clicking on the close button,  it will be deleted from the date table

Answer (score 0):

```
 onChangeDate(value) {
    this.setState({date: value});
 };


onChange{this.onChangeDate.bind(this)}
```